# Code is returning a list of numbers when it should only return 1

Tags: python, numpy

Sorry for bad terminology here, I'm new to python.

I have a code that produces a long list of integers (180 of them), but only a single '1'. I want to count the number of 1s in this list and then print that. I know it should only be printing 1, but instead it produces a 180 number long list, where there are 179 '0's, and 1 '1', I'm very confused and can't find anything like this online

```
for i in range(0, 179):
    imgr = ndimage.rotate(img, i)
    start_row, start_col = int(0), int(0)
    end_row, end_col = int(Y), int(width)
    cropped_top = imgr[start_row:end_row , start_col:end_col]
    start_row, start_col = int(Y), int(0)
    end_row, end_col = int(height), int(width)
    cropped_bot = imgr[start_row:end_row , start_col:end_col]
    D1 = cv2.matchShapes(cropped_top, cropped_bot, cv2.CONTOURS_MATCH_I2, 0)  
    D2 = D1*100     
    D3 = math.ceil(D2)
    D4 = np.array(D3)
    D5 = (D4 == 1).sum()
    print(D5)
```

Edited to include code as text instead of image, made a mistake.
I expect print(D5) to just print the number 1 as that is the actual number of '1's, but it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-----------------------**NOTICE**-----------------------
The cv2.matchShapes returns a value which shows how much two shapes are similar to each other; the lower the result, the better match it is.
[python: cv2.matchshapes documentation](http://www.opencv.org.cn/opencvdoc/2.3.2/html/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv2.matchShapes)
---------------------**CONCLUSION**---------------------
So it doesn't return a numpy array, and it's a float number.
The variable D3 is just a number and D4 will be an numpy array consist of 1 number.
If the value of D3 was 1, D5 would be 1 and if the D3 was something else, the value of D5 would be 0.

If you want those numbers together and not separately, you can define a variable (for example D6) as a list before the for loop and append the D5 to it; something like this:

```
D6 = list()
for i in range(0, 179):
   .
   .
   .
   D5 = (D4 == 1).sum()
   D6.append(D5)
print(D6)
```

Comment: So when I get a list of 180 numbers from the loop, it’s actually not a list, and just 180 separate numbers? Is there a way to combine them into a list so that I can do D5 to find the total number of ‘1’s

Comment: Yes, exactly Andrew. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answer? @Andrew

Comment: Hi @Andrew, I will be so delighted if you choose my answer as the correct one✅, since apparently it helped you, and no one else has posted any answer. Cheers.